# Swift: Using a slider to modify an image - and isolating in order to optimize CIImage?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-image

I've been reading the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift) on using a Sepia Filter to modify an image and then show the results. I thought i'd get away with just slapping a slider onto it. No such luck. It updates like marmite on tar on glue. I was hoping to have almost-realtime updates of the image while moving the slider.

Note: the image I'm trying to put in has Mode:Aspect Fit  enabled, but whenever I move the slider, the SepiaFilter changes it to Mode:ScaleToFill - thus stretching the image. I haven't figured out what to do about that either.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("IMG_0015_For_Swift", withExtension: "jpg")!
let beginImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")!
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!

@IBAction func Slider(sender: AnyObject) { 
    filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(CGFloat(sliderValue.value), forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
    let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage!)
    self.imageViewer.image = newImage
}
```

How would I go about doing this in a better fashion? Knowing how to reset the resulting image back to Mode:ScaleToFill wouldn't be too bad either.

Comment: Heh, UISlider sends events very often, as I know, so you probably can try not to perform updates each time. May be wait until user rise his finger up, or add a timer. You also may consider drawing in the background thread, for more smooth interaction.

Comment: @kelin Well, this is a case of TIL: Buttons and Sliders don't need to just go "Value Changed" but can also do "Touch Up Inside" - which then does the update.

Comment: Ah, the case of TIL, of course. How could I forget!

Answer (score 1):

Wait, it is performing like marmite on tar or marmite on glue? We can't help you unless we know what's going on! :)

(I hadn't heard either of those expressions before. I gather you're in Oz? Here in the northern latitudes we use the expression "Like molasses in January", but that wouldn't make much sense in the Southern Hemisphere. Molasses would probably be pretty thin in January in NSW.)

Don't load the image each time. Load it in viewDidLoad and save it into an instance variable. Also don't create the filter each time. Make it a lazily loaded property.

Those 2 changes should make a huge difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Duncan! I'm actually from Finland. Most of us try to steer away from direct translations of Finnish quotes - the one here would've been "Like a flea in tar". I had to come up with impromptu ones and they were awkward.

Regards your suggestions: I've tried moving let beginImage + let filter + filter.setValue  to viewdidload but then the updatergb doesn't like listening to filter.SetValue with the GreenSlider. not sure how to proceed. I tried to do a   let filterer=filter  to try and bridge the gap, but.. I'm just "???" to be honest.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. Edit your question with updated code.

Comment: I re-edited the code. I hope it is now less confused.